# Are there any entries for User Level Threads in the Thread Table maintained by the OS?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I was studying about ULTs and KLTs and had this doubt in mind . If the OS cannot differentiate between a ULT and a process then does it have any ULT entries in its Thread Table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the OS cannot differentiate between a ULT and a process then does
>   it have any ULT entries in its Thread Table ?

No -- as far as the OS is concerned, User Level Threads do not exist.  Rather, there is just a single thread/process, which is doing "interesting things" with calls to setjmp() and longjmp().

Comment: Then where does the address of the TCB get stored and how is it managed ?

Comment: It would be a data structure inside the user process, just like any other user-level data structure.  It would be managed by the user-level threads library.

Comment: Okay Thank You . I understood :)

Answer (score 2):

## No.

Operating system (kernel) only knows about kernel level threads and have no knowledge of user level threads. User level threads are managed by user library that provides thread functionality.

For example Linux doesn’t differentiate between a thread and process. The entity that can be scheduled is represented by `task_struct` data structure.
So when your library wants to create some threads it asks kernel to create (using clone ()) corresponding `task_structs`. Your library may ask for only one `task_struct` in which case all your user level threads are multiplexed on the same task_struct or it may ask for one `task_struct` for each user level thread in which case every user level thread can be considered by kernel for scheduling because every thread has a `task_struct`.

So in summary we can say that
Kernel only knows about kernel level threads. User level threads are created and managed by the respective library.